# Protect UserInterfaceOnly and EnableOutlining

Tags: c#, excel

I am creating an addin for Excel. It is protecting the sheets in the workbook:

```
public static void ProtectSheetUi(_Worksheet sheet, string password)
{
    sheet.EnableOutlining = true;
    sheet.Protect(password, Contents: true, UserInterfaceOnly: true, AllowFormattingCells: true,
        AllowFormattingColumns: true, AllowFormattingRows: true);
}
```

But the problem is that when I close and reopen the workbook, grouping/ungrouping doesn't work. This is because UserInterfaceOnly is not persistent.
In the workbook level, I could unprotect and protect the sheets again when it is being opened. But how can achieve this with an add-in?

Answer (score 3):

The `UserInterfaceOnly` setting is not saved when you close the workbook. You will have to reset it when the workbook is opened. The best place to do this is in the `Workbook_Open` event procedure. So you need to handle that in your Add-In. For example (*Doing this from memory so please ignore the typos/syntax errors*)

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.WorkbookOpen += 
    new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookOpenEventHandler(Application_WorkbookOpen);
}

void Application_WorkbookOpen(Excel.Workbook Wb)
{
   //~~> Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Would I have to re-protect the worksheets? This means that I need to store the password somewhere. Can I only set the UserInterfaceOnly property to true?

Comment: AFAIK and I could be wrong but Unfortunately yes, you will have to unprotect and reprotect it for `UserInterfaceOnly` to take effect.